# Buildozer failed to execute the last command: The headers or library files could not be found for zlib

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, zlib, buildozer

I have been trying to generate an .apk with buildozer. The .apk is successfully generated, but it crashes each time due to the following error:

```
setup.py build_ext -v

  File "setup.py", line 622, in build_extensions
    raise RequiredDependencyException(f)
__main__.RequiredDependencyException: zlib

  STDOUT:
running build_ext


The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

I have tried all the possible solutions found for similar errors, such as:

Downgrade pip:

```
python -m pip install pip==19.3.1
```

Change Pillow's version:

```
pip install  Pillow==6.2.2
```

Installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get python-dev py-pip jpeg-dev zlib-dev
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev
```

But none of them solved the problem. I'm using Python version 3.8.12. And I'm running on WSL:Ubuntu virtual machine.

I would very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass the issue by using `cv2` instead of `Pillow`, definitely not the best approach.